# I need to compare the body of postman request with an XHR from another website

Tags: json, postman

I'm new to programming and I need to configure a test in postman that compares the body of the response I made in it with the body of an XHR file from a request made on a website (I believe both are in json format).

Thing is, the only thing I'm able to do right now is a code like this

var body = JSON.parse(responseBody); // I believe this sets as a variable the code
tests["compare"] = body.lineiwanttocompare[0] = "copy&paste-line-from-other-website-response";

To access that last info I go to the website, make a request, go to Inspect element > Network > Select XHR > Click the name of that .json > Look at the preview > copy content I want to compare.

Thing is, what I want to compare exactly is a value that changes regularly, so I believe the method I'm using right now will not be useful if I want to automate this, for example.

I've been reading a lot things like making 'pm.sendRequest' or 'fetch' or 'stringify' but nothing really seems to work.
I though about making something like a new variable with the url of that .json request from the website and compare the lines I want to compare but that isn't really giving me results as it gives back errors like 'property undefined'.

Any help? I'm a really new begginner so if more explanation is needed to help I will provide. Also appreciate long answers that explain what code is doing because unt

Comment: you have an endpoint for the json response you get from the Networks calls ?
If yes, i can think of a solution that would help you to compare the json with the response body of the request in Postman.

Comment: Hi! Yes I think I do, if by endpoint you mean an URL that containts the whole response.